# Send Filestream to Client to be downloaded, through Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am building a Node.js application that takes in a string, uses it in a function, which then returns a Filestream. How do I send that Filestream through Express, to be downloaded by the client, with a specific name?

```
dls.get('/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    function(req.params.id).solution()
    next()
})
app.use('/download', dls)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not real clear what the code you show is attempting to do since we have no idea what `dls` is.

To send a filestream to the client, you do `readstream.pipe(res)` where readstream would be the filestream you want to send.  To direct the browser to download it as a file with a suggested name, you set the [content-disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header as in `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"`.

If you're trying to have one request that sets things up for another request that can use a generic URL like `/download` to get the content, then that is more involved as you would have to have some place (like a server-side session) to store some state that would tell the `/download` route which user and which download to send.

Comment: @JasonLorrca - Are you here?  Any feedback on this answer.  Any clarification of your question.  Since it looks like you may be new here, this place doesn't work very well if you post and just disappear for a long time.  YOU will get a lot more out of it and get much better feedback from helpers if you stay around and interact with the people that try to help you.  This place is different than many online forums where you might post and come back the next day.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Dls is an Express router. I will try it now and see if it works. Sorry about not responding faster!

Comment: @JasonLorrca - Does this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and also earn yourself some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.